# How to set SameSite to none in Rails 6 API with CreateReactApp?

Tags: heroku, react-redux, cross-domain, session-cookies, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 app acting as an API for a frontend app originally created with create-react-app.  I am trying to store a session token to preserve login on page refresh.

When running locally, Chrome shows that `SameSite=Lax` but the session token is stored anyway.  On the live site, SameSite is still Lax, but Chrome gives a little warning saying that the Set-Cookie header was blocked because it came from cross-site response.  Both the frontend and api are deployed on Heroku in separate repos.

I've tried a number of things:

- secure_headers gem, with the following in `app/config/initializers/secure_headers.rb`:

```
SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
  config.cookies = {
    secure: true, # mark all cookies as "Secure"
    httponly: true, # mark all cookies as "HttpOnly"
    samesite: {
      lax: false
    }
  }
end
```

I have the following in `app/config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_session_id',
  :domain => :all,
  :same_site => :none,
  :secure => :true,
  :tld_length => 3
```

I've tried cookie_serializer, although I commented everything out of that file.

I have the rack-cors gem, with the following in the cors.rb initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:5000', 'https://frontend-auth-frontend.herokuapp.com'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: true,
      exposedHeaders: ["Set-Cookie"]
  end
end
```

I've tried a few other gems I saw recommended on SO but I don't remember all of them.

So... yea, how do I set SameSite so that my heroku frontend (react) can store cookies from the heroku api (rails 6)?

I can provide other info about the project, specific versions, etc., just not sure what else would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I am under the same exact circumstances right now

Comment: @user17443811 I don't think I ever did, and I don't think I even have this project anymore, sorry

Answer (score 0):

the following code should set sameSite to none  (the key is in the last line)

```
//config/application.rb

   config.api_only = true

    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
             key: '_cookie_name', path: '/', same_site: :None, secure: true
```